# volume of the largest rectangular box

Tags: calculus, optimization

Find the volume of the largest rectangular box with edges parallel to the axes that can be inscribed in the ellipsoid
$$x^2/16+y^2/49+z^2/9=1.$$

Hint: By symmetry, you can restrict your attention to the first octant (where $x, y, z \ge 0$), and assume your volume has the form $V =8xyz$.

Comment: Assuming this question doesn't just get closed, are you in multi-variate calculus?  Have you had Lagrange multipliers?  Also, what have you attempted so far?

Comment: yeah i think that this question need Lagrange multiples

Comment: You will need to show some work on that process, or this question looks like it's going to get closed...

Comment: i was trying to find the radius then after that stretching it then finding the volume, I am lost

Comment: You have the function $ \ V(x,y,z) \ = 8xyz \ $ , subject to the constraint function $ \ g(x,y,z) \ = \frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{y^2}{49} + \frac{z^2}{9} - 1 \ . $  You need to find the gradients $ \ \nabla f \ $ and $ \ \nabla g \ $ , set up the equation $ \ \nabla f = \lambda \cdot \nabla g \ $ , and produce equations between each of the three components.  This will tell you something about the relation between the three coordinate variables. **Henning Makholm**'s approach is very nice, but is not the one you are being taught just now...

Comment: I got 4/27 and I have to idea how i got it, it's wrong

Comment: Are you able to edit your post to show what you did?  What did you find from the Lagrange equations?

Comment: dF/dx - k dG/dx = 0 
dF/dy - k dG/dy = 0 
dF/dz - k dG/dz = 0 
G = 1

Comment: You should have equations $ \ 8yz - k (\frac{2x}{16}) = 0 \ , \ 8xz - k (\frac{2y}{49}) = 0 , $ etc.  Solve for $ \ k \ $ in each equation and set pairs of results equal to one another.  You will get equations such as $ \ 16y^2 = 49x^2 \ , $ and so on.  These give you the relative proportions of $ \ x \ , \ y \ , $ and $ \ z \ . $  You can then eliminate two of the variables in the equation for the ellipsoid (your constraint equation), get a value for the remaining variable, and thus find values for _half_ the lengths of the sides of the box.

Answer (score 4):

Scale the entire situation by 1/4 along the $x$ axis, 1/7 along the $y$ axis, and 1/3 along the $z$ axis. This scaling doesn't change which boxes are larger or smaller than others, but now you're just inscribing a box in a unit *sphere*, where it should be intuitively clear how to maximize it. Then scale that solution back to the original coordinates.

Comment: Of course, depending on what level of calculus course OP is in, a grader might not give full credit for this approach... (But it _is_ a wonderful property of the optimization.)

Comment: I still did not understand